# How to produce count of Access Lists an Enrollee enrolled in?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have tables `AccessList`, `Enrollment` and `AccessListEnrollmentMapping`.

AccessList:

```
int id
varchar name
```

Enrollment:

```
int id
varchar firstname
varchar lastname
```

AccessListEnrollmentMapping:

```
int id
int AccessListId
int EnrollmentId
```

An Enrollment can be on multiple AccessLists. When I delete an AccessList, I want Enrollments that are only on that one AccessList to be deleted. If the Enrollments are on multiple AccessLists, I want to keep them.

This will give me all Enrollments per AccessList:

```
select EnrollmentId from AccessListEnrollmentMapping where AccessListId = 3;
```

This will give how many AccessLists an Enrollment is on:

```
select count(*) from AccessListEnrollmentMapping where EnrollmentId = 1;
```

I want to"loop over" all Enrollment id's in an AccessList to see how many other access lists that Enrollment is in. I tried :

```
with enrollments_in_acl as (
    select EnrollmentId
    from AccessListEnrollmentMapping
    where AccessListId = 3
) select count(*)
from AccessListEnrollmentMapping
where EnrollmentId = enrollments_in_acl.EnrollmentId;
```

I get this error:

```
no such column: enrollments_in_acl.EnrollmentId: with enrollments_in_acl as (select EnrollmentId from AccessListEnrollmentMapping where AccessListId = 3) select count(*) from AccessListEnrollmentMapping where EnrollmentId = enrollments_in_acl.EnrollmentId
```

Is a Common Table Expression what I need?

Database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `AccessList`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AccessList` (
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `Name`  TEXT
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Enrollment`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Enrollment` (
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `FirstName` TEXT,
    `LastName`  TEXT
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `AccessListEnrollmentMapping`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AccessListEnrollmentMapping` (
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `EnrollmentId`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `AccessListId`  INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO AccessList (Name) VALUES ("ACL01");
INSERT INTO AccessList (Name) VALUES ("ACL02");
INSERT INTO AccessList (Name) VALUES ("ACL03");
INSERT INTO AccessList (Name) VALUES ("ACL04");
INSERT INTO AccessList (Name) VALUES ("ACL05");

INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Anthony","Stark");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Steven","Rogers");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Robert","Banner");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Stephen","Strange");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Virginia","Potts");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Nicholas","Fury");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Phillip","Coulson");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Melinda","May");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Natalia","Romanova");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Clinton","Barton");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Peter","Parker");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("James","Barnes");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Elizabeth","Ross");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Glenn","Talbot");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Thaddeus","Ross");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Carol","Danvers");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Jemma","Simmons");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Leopold","Fitz");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Margaret","Carter");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Howard","Stark");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Maria","Hill");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Henry","Pym");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Janet","van Dyne");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Jonathan","Garrett");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Grant","Ward");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Sharon","Carter");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Barbara","Morse");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Wade","Wilson");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("James","Howlett");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Wanda","Maximoff");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Peter","Quill");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Scott","Lang");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Anna","LeBeau");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Jean","Grey");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Mary","Watson");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Reed","Richards");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Charles","Xavier");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Katherine","Pryde");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Daisy","Johnson");
INSERT INTO Enrollment (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ("Wade","Wilson");

INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL01'),1);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL01'),2);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL01'),3);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL01'),4);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL01'),5);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL01'),6);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL01'),7);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL02'),8);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL02'),9);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL02'),10);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL02'),11);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL02'),12);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL02'),13);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL02'),14);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL03'),15);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL03'),16);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL03'),17);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL03'),18);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL03'),19);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL03'),20);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL03'),21);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL03'),22);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL04'),23);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL04'),24);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL04'),25);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL04'),26);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL04'),27);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL04'),28);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL04'),29);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL04'),30);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'),31);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'),32);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'),33);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'),34);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'),35);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'),36);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'),37);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'),38);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'),39);

INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL01'), 40);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL02'), 40);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL03'), 40);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL04'), 40);
INSERT INTO AccessListEnrollmentMapping (AccessListId,EnrollmentId) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE Name = 'ACL05'), 40);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cte` should be referenced in `from`. You can't refer to columns from it with out doing so.

```
with enrollments_in_acl as (
select EnrollmentId
from AccessListEnrollmentMapping
where AccessListId = 3
) select count(*)
from AccessListEnrollmentMapping am
join enrollments_in_acl ea -- >>>>cte being referenced here
where am.EnrollmentId = ea.EnrollmentI
```

That said, the problem you have doesn't require a cte. Just use conditional aggregation.

```
select sum(case when enrollmentId = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from AccessListEnrollmentMapping
where AccessListId = 3
```

Comment: This only gives me the answer for **one** Enrollment. I need to loop over all Enrollments on a particular AccessList.

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer based on comments...

```
SELECT aem.EnrollmentId
     , COUNT(DISTINCT aem.AccessListId) as AccessListId_count
  FROM AccessListEnrollmentMapping aem
 GROUP BY aem.EnrollmentId
 ORDER BY aem.EnrollmentId;
```

This gives you the distinct count of `AccessListId` values by `EnrollmenId`.

Let me know if I have understood what your desired output is...and if not consider adding your desired output to the question as an ASCII Table. This tool makes it easy: [ASCII Tables](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

This is the [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5s7yQ56aaT4Tk537eTjadh/5) that I built.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185576/discussion-between-jon-jaussi-and-brian).